# Confirmation message only for the Browser closing. Not at the time of window tab closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I am trying to detect *browser close button* clicked by user. Hence I tried below code after searching in web :=

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(window).bind('click', function(event) {
   if(event.target.href) 
         $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
 });
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(event) {
     return 'pls save ur work';
 });
 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <a href="test2.cfm">reload</a>
 </body>
```

This works absolutely fine for Browser closing and window tab closing event. This will give confirmation message on closing both.

**But I want message only for the Browser closing. Not at the time of window tab closed.**
Is there any solution ?

Reason is I wanted to detect the Browser close because only when browser is closed I wanted to update some data of the signed in user and clear the session of the user.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: No, I don't believe that there's any way to distinguish why the `beforeunload` event was fired, whether it's the tab, window or browser.

Comment: As @DavidThomas notes, there is no way to do what you are wanting, and that is on purpose. The only reason it works when you close the browser is because that *also* closes the tab.

Comment: Maybe you can do that by making a browser extension... but still making little sense.

Comment: I want to detect the browser close because only when browser is closed I wanted to update some data of the signed in user and clear the session of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't any solution for that. The `window` attribute isn't bound to a real window (in terms of operating system) but to the environment it is running in (and that's actually in modern browsers a tab). That's for example why there is this *feature* called sandbox in Chrome, where a crashing tab doesn't affect other tabs. So closing a tab or closing a window won't make any difference to any of the JavaScript functions. Why should you want to have the warning only before closing the whole browser window? The work will be lost even when closing the tab!

Comment: I wanted to detect the browser close because only when browser is closed I wanted to update some data  of the signed in user and clear the session of the user.